# Windows 7 won't see Ubuntu 12.04 shares

Tags: 12.04, windows-7, samba, file-sharing

I have a desktop with Ubuntu 12.04 running, with Samba installed. My laptop, which has Windows 7 on it, can connect to the linux machine via IP, the Ubuntu machine flawlessly navigates to the Windows machine, and both machines see each other's netbios names when nbtscan is run on each machine. So it seems that it should be working.

Regardless, on the Windows 7 laptop, browsing via the network browser will not show the network name of the linux machine.

I'm thinking it's something on the Windows machine, since the netbios names seem to be propogating. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Oddly enough I discovered if I type in the Ubuntu's machine UNC name, it works perfectly. Even shows on the left panel after doing that, but in the right panel (where it says network) its missing. Some bug in Windows 7 I guess.